# Identifying Crash in Symbolized Crash Report

Tags: ios, xcode

I've had a crash within my native iOS App (which runs fine on simulator, only error on a device) I've been unable to identify the issue.  The crash happens while the splash screen is shown, before the initial view controller is shown.  Here are the 3 steps I've done thus far:

1) turned on all exception breakpoints.  By doing so, the exception shows up in main.m.  Here is the code:

```
 //  main.m
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "idcAppDelegate.h"

 int main(int argc, char * argv[])
 {

@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([idcAppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

2) looked at the crash log and symboized it.  Here is the output.  The only view controller shown in line 5 of crash report (below) is EngineeringViewController.m with line #741 of my code.  I checked that code and included that in #3 below.  Also, as a test I put a breakpoint prior to that line of code being called, and it never reached that code.  Any insight to the issues would be appreciated.

```
 Incident Identifier: 1C053572-AFE5-4EB6-A95C-9E4459B860A7
 CrashReporter Key:   f97ebe907a31ab39c017e93a637e9e195e90d8f4
 Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
 Process:             idcdoor [267]
 Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8ED83A36-2A92-4601-9265-    392A9E97E89B/idcdoor.app/idcdoor
 Identifier:          com.zen.idcdoor
 Version:             1.0 (1.0)
 Code Type:           ARM (Native)
 Parent Process:      launchd [1]

 Date/Time:           2014-11-01 10:26:23.652 -0500
 Launch Time:         2014-11-01 10:26:20.975 -0500
 OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B411)
 Report Version:      105

 Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
 Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000014
 Triggered by Thread:  0

 Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
 Thread 0 Crashed:
 0   libsystem_c.dylib              0x354877d4 strlen + 28
 1   CoreFoundation                 0x2771440c __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 7052
 2   CoreFoundation                 0x2771285c _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 76
 3   Foundation                     0x2837f86e -[NSPlaceholderString     initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 134
 4   Foundation                     0x2837f770 +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 56
 5   idcdoor                        0x000a8e48 -[EngineeringViewController pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:] (EngineeringViewController.m:741)
 6   UIKit                          0x2accc60a -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 2546
 7   UIKit                          0x2accbb54 -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 324
 8   UIKit                          0x2accb994 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 52
 9   UIKit                          0x2accb7cc -[UITableView _updateContentSize] + 340
 10  UIKit                          0x2acd151e -[UITableView didMoveToWindow] + 66
 11  UIKit                          0x2abfbe50 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1308
 12  UIKit                          0x2ac1ac96 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 46
 13  UIKit                          0x2abfbbc0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 652
 14  UIKit                          0x2abfbbc0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 652
 15  UIKit                          0x2abfb4d4 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 108
 16  UIKit                          0x2abfb3e8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 424
 17  UIKit                          0x2ac0584a -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1458
 18  UIKit                          0x2ac0528e -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 26
 19  UIKit                          0x2ae58cb4 -[UIPickerView layoutSubviews] + 3212
 20  UIKit                          0x2ae5a322 -[UIPickerView selectedRowInComponent:] + 42
 21  UIKit                          0x2ae56bfc -[UIPickerView _updateSelectedRows] + 124
 22  UIKit                          0x2ae56d0a -[UIPickerView didMoveToWindow] + 94
 23  UIKit                          0x2abfbe50 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1308
 24  UIKit                          0x2abfbbc0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 652
 25  UIKit                          0x2abfbbc0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 652
 26  UIKit                          0x2abfbbc0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 652
 27  UIKit                          0x2abfb4d4 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 108
 28  UIKit                          0x2abfb3e8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 424
 29  UIKit                          0x2ac0584a -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1458
 30  UIKit                          0x2ac0528e -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 26
 31  UIKit                          0x2acb142a -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 474
 32  UIKit                          0x2acb1246 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:] + 22
 33  UIKit                          0x2aca8af2 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2282
 34  UIKit                          0x2aca7f7e -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 574
 35  UIKit                          0x2aca7ce8 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 40
 36  UIKit                          0x2aca7c7c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 180
 37  UIKit                          0x2abfc4d2 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 510
 38  QuartzCore                     0x2a624a08 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 132
 39  QuartzCore                     0x2a6203e0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 356
 40  QuartzCore                     0x2a620268 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
 41  QuartzCore                     0x2a61fc4c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 220
 42  QuartzCore                     0x2a61fa50 CA::Transaction::commit() + 320
 43  UIKit                          0x2ae601c0 -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 40
 44  UIKit                          0x2ae60f68 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2508
 45  UIKit                          0x2ae6b374 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
 46  UIKit                          0x2ae5f384 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 128
 47  FrontBoardServices             0x2decc0e6 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 10
 48  CoreFoundation                 0x2770639a __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 10
 49  CoreFoundation                 0x2770565c __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 212
 50  CoreFoundation                 0x27704196 __CFRunLoopRun + 1710
 51  CoreFoundation                 0x2765220c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
 52  CoreFoundation                 0x2765201e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
 53  UIKit                          0x2ac633ea -[UIApplication _run] + 554
 54  UIKit                          0x2ac5e1cc UIApplicationMain + 1436
 55  idcdoor                        0x000af77e main (main.m:17)
 56  libdyld.dylib                  0x3546aaac start + 0

 Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
 Thread 1:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3551d2a0 kevent64 + 24
 1   libdispatch.dylib              0x354569fc _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 276
 2   libdispatch.dylib              0x3544c20e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

 Thread 2:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x355319cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x355abea8 _pthread_wqthread + 788
 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x355abb80 start_wqthread + 4

 Thread 3:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x355319cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x355abea8 _pthread_wqthread + 788
 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x355abb80 start_wqthread + 4

 Thread 4:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x355319cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x355abea8 _pthread_wqthread + 788
 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x355abb80 start_wqthread + 4

 Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
 r0: 0x00000014    r1: 0x00000014      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x01010101
 r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x277ab8d9      r6: 0x001ca2f8      r7: 0x001ca2f0
 r8: 0x001ca884    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x001ca434     r11: 0x277ab8d9
 ip: 0x00000018    sp: 0x001ca2f0      lr: 0x27714411      pc: 0x354877d4
 cpsr: 0x60000010

 Binary Images:
 0x9e000 - 0xbdfff idcdoor armv7  <3a3e81a535e33b749617ea74b35051a4> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8ED83A36-2A92-4601-9265-392A9E97E89B/idcdoor.app/idcdoor
 0x264f000 - 0x265afff GAXClient armv7s  <2a03ff3e6ca83b138ffe5e1436d3a686> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GAXClient.bundle/GAXClient
 0x1fee5000 - 0x1ff08fff dyld armv7s  <b01d37db5b0d3a2ea1ccf17afc40a896> /usr/lib/dyld
 0x25d80000 - 0x25d88fff AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7s  <46e9b9bae13d3590971aca226c70bb90> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
 0x25f48000 - 0x25f63fff libJapaneseConverter.dylib armv7s  <708b951369ca3c6ca3c04cff645cb4af> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libJapaneseConverter.dylib
 0x25f64000 - 0x25f85fff libKoreanConverter.dylib armv7s  <12d4496cb7e234ef9248a8133281466f> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libKoreanConverter.dylib
 0x25f8d000 - 0x25f9bfff libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib armv7s  <710dea62fe2532bd833dc37458e8df31> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib
 0x25f9e000 - 0x25fb0fff libTraditionalChineseConverter.dylib armv7s  <b671c9d6a27e3125ab87d2b889e52885> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libTraditionalChineseConverter.dylib
 0x261d6000 - 0x26342fff AVFoundation armv7s  <20cb3fb302c83ede8cc708d8dea2b480> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
 0x26343000 - 0x263a1fff libAVFAudio.dylib armv7s  <07753e16a2e136e2bbe7937c1d2833f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
 0x263db000 - 0x263dbfff Accelerate armv7s  <3c10ee15d8363fa58b719f2abca91b06> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
 0x263ec000 - 0x26607fff vImage armv7s  <3358de09601333a2881365e5c74c681e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
 0x26608000 - 0x266eefff libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <b46b7fd3985f371ca26b10f268965e63> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
 0x266ef000 - 0x269b3fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <eb228c255d9e349391cd6b227a9d2744> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
 0x269b4000 - 0x269c5fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib armv7s  <d2e989bc1bad320b918c37d3642db4b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
 0x269c6000 - 0x26a42fff libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <07cf0625bd813336920eb5b62f99be06> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
 0x26a43000 - 0x26a55fff libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <07997e6e46fa35a18c6ddacf62f326d8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
 0x26a56000 - 0x26a56fff vecLib armv7s  <108b763f155130828fa123813e3ff5f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
 0x26a57000 - 0x26a7dfff Accounts armv7s  <7540bbbab44638cbbfc6f8e660b882e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
 0x26a7f000 - 0x26aeffff AddressBook armv7s  <f14b87a5995235f7b4758b9177eacfff> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
 0x26af0000 - 0x26c14fff AddressBookUI armv7s  <4cbc3a35503334398504bec12f184406> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
 0x26dad000 - 0x27020fff AudioToolbox armv7s  <6af7bb73fc8a3820aaeddf4be11d76d1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
 0x2718b000 - 0x27313fff CFNetwork armv7s  <447c648544f63bad945945978a4420cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
 0x27314000 - 0x27395fff CloudKit armv7s  <a36362766d2d34a89f0375dc3af0b266> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
 0x27396000 - 0x273f5fff CoreAudio armv7s  <fc17e188a69f32b8b7a5eb739e71628a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
 0x27410000 - 0x2742dfff CoreBluetooth armv7s  <7013619ef098351e9327893736f9ac75> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
 0x2742e000 - 0x27639fff CoreData armv7s  <c9df4ab3eb933030a3cec50334b917ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
 0x2763a000 - 0x27966fff CoreFoundation armv7s  <88f8b217c0ee3ea99fc535279a274e51> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 0x27967000 - 0x27a91fff CoreGraphics armv7s  <89608951c9173d66ba6318cfe83636cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
 0x27ad1000 - 0x27ad3fff libCGXType.A.dylib armv7s  <e655cd9db7ee35779038050110716bdf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
 0x27ad4000 - 0x27adefff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib armv7s  <edc7a2d9b3ec34599184c14a1558e306> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
 0x27cc6000 - 0x27ce1fff libRIP.A.dylib armv7s  <7245d28cd0683999ba311e1f9c44eaf0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
 0x27ce2000 - 0x27df0fff CoreImage armv7s  <5c9817ffa8c939878f34e92794fe01d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
 0x27df1000 - 0x27e48fff CoreLocation armv7s  <a25b4e5cd9db3552b17f6f933c268b4e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
 0x27e7a000 - 0x27f14fff CoreMedia armv7s  <c0207b0eb8a6372c82765e3f9aaae9c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
 0x27f15000 - 0x27fd4fff CoreMotion armv7s  <eaf2bec24a9a339b8a72e66a50f84195> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
 0x27fd5000 - 0x28033fff CoreTelephony armv7s  <d387fea5262f3a1a9b915eda86a9c521> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
 0x28034000 - 0x280fbfff CoreText armv7s  <27a6c9f02e0c3fcdb25aa629dbac8420> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
 0x280fc000 - 0x28111fff CoreVideo armv7s  <710cbdb8798d3e7e862a5c77ebb278b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
 0x28112000 - 0x28207fff EventKit armv7s  <f5e8d9857bca3d30a82884f74acccdd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
 0x2837e000 - 0x28580fff Foundation armv7s  <dae281def68e3062826ad439cc878f35> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
 0x285ad000 - 0x285ccfff GSS armv7s  <3d6d5fcf16673331b532dc80bc9cb004> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/GSS
 0x28660000 - 0x286b6fff IOKit armv7s  <694427785d6b3b158555dbb2de06ba5d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
 0x286b7000 - 0x288f9fff ImageIO armv7s  <7805efbe771f3abe8eb78f8a11e43510> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
 0x288fa000 - 0x28c48fff JavaScriptCore armv7s  <8efe7fde7fc334d3b4e7154fd1ad7934> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
 0x28f25000 - 0x28f2dfff MediaAccessibility armv7s  <39f640b059a43b609c3f03d2c53ccca3> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
 0x28f2e000 - 0x29107fff MediaPlayer armv7s  <c97f5d8967cd331687edef49d2e330ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
 0x29108000 - 0x29481fff MediaToolbox armv7s  <61a8287d7db23902ace54438be5d01dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
 0x29482000 - 0x29540fff MessageUI armv7s  <4d650e3067b53974b00534275f6f4e90> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
 0x29541000 - 0x295adfff Metal armv7s  <55c278f571e43337a9f50f33fd7a0e19> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
 0x295ae000 - 0x2963efff MobileCoreServices armv7s  <d309a94eb41f3828888fea191d26c2b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
 0x2a11a000 - 0x2a122fff OpenGLES armv7s  <da72e0ef6bad373e9f10a34e7e8e69c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
 0x2a124000 - 0x2a124fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <19d9172837f5361d938ae1757caf9c37> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
 0x2a125000 - 0x2a127fff libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7s  <ecc01c4cd2aa3cfabe2cb655e944d675> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
 0x2a128000 - 0x2a12bfff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <f9bbda54797d3b119f02b904b5b616b8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
 0x2a12c000 - 0x2a134fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <a4f8148c427c3a1da2d6e4f7d8f44db0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
 0x2a135000 - 0x2a177fff libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <25bf18582842387aadbef55023603f1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
 0x2a618000 - 0x2a76afff QuartzCore armv7s  <f279312e24013b3facfd0701a8f856f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
 0x2a76b000 - 0x2a7befff QuickLook armv7s  <4faa07b11c763d2e8535a9eeae067d73> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
 0x2a9ad000 - 0x2a9edfff Security armv7s  <de3cef25d1443557af5def374133b390> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
 0x2ab91000 - 0x2abedfff SystemConfiguration armv7s  <f0007f16cef530dcb1681ab29db8e311> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
 0x2abf0000 - 0x2b491fff UIKit armv7s  <30f3605a26bc3155a5dbffdf1f30d2ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
 0x2b492000 - 0x2b4f9fff VideoToolbox armv7s  <2a114ceb99013b3bb24c7d5544f0a575> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
 0x2b4fa000 - 0x2b6dffff WebKit armv7s  <adbe79a7e1fe3e4a96388bbead166d3f> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
 0x2ba00000 - 0x2ba0bfff AOSNotification armv7s  <9692b7bd225438e7b7832f56454a2857> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification
 0x2bacf000 - 0x2bad6fff AccessibilityUI armv7s  <5b632cc5cff034f9a3e1e533421dc2f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accessibility.framework/Frameworks/AccessibilityUI.framework/AccessibilityUI
 0x2baee000 - 0x2baf1fff AccessibilityUIUtilities armv7s  <e7c5cd1c1c223fad9e1b1d9471c1044a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accessibility.framework/Frameworks/AccessibilityUIUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUIUtilities
 0x2baf4000 - 0x2baf7fff ZoomServices armv7s  <734b9fb4cf9b30f79573a25e471d55dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accessibility.framework/Frameworks/ZoomServices.framework/ZoomServices
 ....
```

3) here is code from EngineeringViewController.m

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if([pickerView isEqual: _pickerPreferredId]){
        return sizeof(Preffered_ID);
    }else if([pickerView isEqual: _pickerDrum]){
        int drumCount = 0;
        if(doorLiftSelection == 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof Select_Drum[10]; i++){
                //line 741
                if([[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",Select_Drum[i][10]] isEqualToString:@"Standard"]){
                    drumCount++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show us the lines around `EngineeringViewController.m:741`.

Comment: @trojanfoe added that code for EngineeringViewController

Comment: What types are you storing in your `Select_Drum`? It looks like you aren't using the good flag in your `NSString stringWithFormat:`

Comment: @Ckouta static char* Select_Drum[11][ 11]

Comment: What do you expect `sizeof Select_Drum[10]` to do? In "C" the unary operator sizeof is used to calculate the size of any *datatype*, measured in the number of bytes required to represent the type.

Comment: @Zaph it's for the for statement.  I replace the i < sizeof Select_Drum[10]; with i < 11 and I receive the exact same crash

Answer (score 1):

At the time of the crash, Select_Drum[i][10] is not a valid C string.

CF is trying to create a CFString/NSString from it and is crashing when trying to strlen() on the string to determine how much memory it needs to allocate for the resulting CFString.

---

As for *why* it's not a valid C string, you'll need to look at it with the debugger, but this line looks *VERY* suspect:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof Select_Drum[10]; i++)
```

I don't think that does what you think it does.